# Show Popup Dialog After The Ending Call in Flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, calllog

I need to show popup dialog after ending the call in flutter like truecaller, I fetch the calls using call log package, but it gives an error : Fatal: No callback registered, So please see the code below and give me any suggestions.

Thank You.

---

```
import 'package:call_log/call_log.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  // Call
  Future<void> fetchCallLogs() async {
    var callLogs = await CallLog.query();
    if (callLogs.isNotEmpty) {
      final lastCall = callLogs.first;
      if (lastCall.callType == CallType.incoming) {
        showAlertDialog(context);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Call Dialog'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    // Create button
    Widget okButton = TextButton(
      child: Text("OK"),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
    );

    // Create AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Simple Alert"),
      content: Text("This is an alert message."),
      actions: [
        okButton,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This Code shows :

`D/me.sodipto.phone_state_background(10136): New broadcast event received...`

`W/FlutterJNI(10136): FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once`

`W/FlutterJNI(10136): FlutterJNI.prefetchDefaultFontManager called more than once`

`I/ResourceExtractor(10136): Found extracted resources res_timestamp-1-1700557316079`

`W/FlutterJNI(10136): FlutterJNI.init called more than once`

`D/me.sodipto.phone_state_background(10136): Phone State event PHONE_RINGING number: 6505551212`

`E/me.sodipto.phone_state_background(10136): Fatal: No callback registered`

I don't Know What is this, so If anyone use calllog pacakge so please tell me the solution.

Comment: Have you had a look at the example?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77521660/show-popup-dialog-after-the-ending-call-in-flutter
Also, since you don't add any query parameters you can just use `CallLog.get()` instead of `query`.